Dimension of the positive cone of a matrix
Given a real matrix $A$, let me call its "positive cone" the space containing all real vectors such that $v^TAv\ge 0$ (I don't know if this concept already has another name). Is there a simple way of finding out the dimension of this space? (e.g. by computing its Jordan form, or its singular value decomposition, etc, without brute force search around its domain)

Such a set is not a subspace, if for no other reason than it does not contain $0$. Given this, what do you mean by the dimension of the space? Do you mean the dimension of the affine hull of the set?

I now wrote $\ge 0$ instead of >0. Its not a vector space, but it is a cone. The dimension is the largest number of linear independent elements. @TheoBendit

A few observations: 1. If there exists $v$ such that $v^\top Av>0$, then the cone contains a ball, and will therefore have full dimension. 2. This occurs when $A$ has a positive eigenvalue. 3. I believe it will also happen if $A$ has an eigenvalue with positive real part.

@TheoBendit What about the case when all the eigenvalues of $A$ have negative real part? (in fact, this was my original interest)

I'm not sure. I can find examples of such matrices where $v^\top A v > 0$ for some $v$, where $A$ is not diagonalisable. Are the negative real parts strictly negative, or just non-positive?
